# Recursion: double call in one return

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int f(int n){
  if (n==0 || n==1)
    return 1;
  else 
    return 2*f(n-1)+2*f(n-2);
}
```

How do you think this in steps, if n=3?
If there was only one "2*f(n-1)", I would have known how to think it, but there are two calls.
Thanks!

Comment: The good news is that you do not have to think about this. The computer is smart enough to do the thinking for you. If you sit down with a piece of paper and a pen, you could reasonably map out maybe 2-3 levels of recursion here, but this quickly gets out of hand. Nothing really useful can be obtained from such an excersize. Perhaps you might want to spend some time studying the purely mathematical concept of "proof by induction". Once you're comfortable with that general proposition, things like this will become second nature.

Comment: I think it would be very useful to do n=3 or even n=5 initial cases by hand on paper. Alternatively, step through it with debugger, just draw function calls on paper as you progress. Understanding what happens here is very important.

Comment: It works exactly the same as if you called two different functions – say, `2*g(n-1)+2*h(n-2)`. There is nothing special about recursive functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.)***

Call graph for `n = 3`, shall be like :

```
=> 2*f(2)+2*f(1);
=> 2*[2*f(1)+2*f(0)] + 2*f(1)
=> 2*[2*1 + 2*1] + 2*f(1)
=> 8 + 2*1
=> 10
```

Comment: OT, Q.E.D. is usually placed at the *end* of a demonstration...  ;)

Comment: @Bob__ Didn't have much words to put before :)

Answer (score 0):

If you turn this in terms of one operation per step you get something like:

```
int f(int n){
    return fcont1(n, n < 2);
}
int fcont1(int n, int nl2) {
    if( nl2 ) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fcont2(n);
    }
}
int fcont2(int nm1){
    return fcont3(n, n-1);
}
int fcont3(int n, int nm1){
    return fcont4(n, f(nm1));
}
int fcont4(int n, int r1){
    return fcont5(r1, n-2);
}
int fcont5(int r1, int nm2){
    return fcont6(r1, f(nm2));
}
int fcont6(int r1, int r2) {
    return fcont7(2*r1, r2);
}
int fcont7(int dr1, int r2) {
    return fcont7(dr1, 2*r2);
}
int fcont7(int dr1, int dr2) {
    return dr1+dr2;
}
```

Of coruse this rewrite ends up using more memory since C does not optimize tail calls but any language that does this is totally the same code with the order of the operations decided.